# How can i call the same child method when i have the list of same child component in parent component in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, components, parent-child

This is parent.html

```html
<child *ngFor="let detail of listContact; let i = index" 
        [detailsItem]="detail" [index]="i">
</child>
```

This is child.compenent

```js
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() index: number;
  @Input() detailsItem: any;
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {

  }
  saveChild(){
console.log('index', this.index);
  }
}
```

And I want to call the method saveChild in parentComponent like this:

```js
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {
  private child: ChildComponent;
  @Input() index: number;
  @Input() detailsItem: any;
  constructor() {
  }
  ngOnInit() {
  }
  save(){
    this.child.saveChild();
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use @ViewChild to run that.

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { ChildComponent } from '../child/child.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-parent',
  templateUrl: './parent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent.component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild(ChildComponent) public child!:ChildComponent

  constructor() { }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.child.childMethod();
  }

}
```

It's going to let you access the properties and methods inside the ChildComponent. However remember to use ngAfterViewInit so that the child is initialised when you try and access it.

Comment: But i want to call child method on another method of parent. Not in ngAfterViewInit()

Comment: You can access the ChildComponent wherever but only after ngAfterViewInit.

Comment: It doesn't call 2 times when i have 2 same child

Comment: I means i user *ngFor to call the child in parent's HTML. and when I have 2 child, it's doesn't call 2 times